# NSSound setChannelMapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssound

I've been trying to figure out how to use setChannelMapping on the NSSound class.  According to the class documentation "channelMapping Audio-channel—to—device–channel mappings for the receiver." Um ok? It then leads me into a maze of unhelpful information with lots of pictures.  I like pictures as much as the next person, but thats not helping me to much.  What do I need to provide to this method to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out (at least in my situation)  It appears that the function accepts a NSArray that has been filled with NSNumber objects.  One NSNumber per channel that you want the audio to be played though.  Set the value of the NSNumber to the channel index.